# How do multiple modal constructions work with ellipsis or inversion?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-inversion, ellipses, multiple-modals

I have been researching on multiple modal constructions, which is a dialect mainly used in
The Southern United States. Unlike Standard English, this dialect allows more than one modal auxiliary per clause. For example, some users of this dialect may say, "You might could go to the store for me."

What I would particularly like to know is about the verbal phrase ellipsis and subject-auxiliary inversion of the multiple modal sentences.

I would like to ask users of this dialect to judge whether the following sentences are grammatical or not.

**about verbal phrase ellipsis**:

(1)

a.    I might could should do that, and you might could should too.

b.    I might could should do that, and you might could too.

(2)

a.  Rose might will can't come tomorrow, but Joe might will can.

b.  Rose might will can't come tomorrow, but Joe might will.

a.  Rose might will can come tomorrow, and Joe might will can too.

b.  Rose might will can come tomorrow, and Joe might will too.

**about subject-auxiliary inversion**:

(1)

a.  Could I might should do that?

b.  Should I might could do that?

(2)

a.  Will Rose might can't come tomorrow?

b.  Can't Rose might will come tomorrow?

Comment: I don't speak such a dialect, but this paper may answer some of your questions: https://journals.lib.unb.ca/index.php/la/article/download/22489/26146/34041

Comment: From that paper: usually the inverted form of "You might could go" is "Could you might go?" But some speakers don't accept inversion of such sentences at all.

Comment: Normally, only a restricted set of pairs of modal verbs are allowed; triple modals are exceedingly rare.

Comment: I appreciate your valuable commnets. I will read the pages you kindly added a link to.

Comment: You'll hafta rely on your language consultants. Only they know how they speak and how they feel about it.

Comment: I will follow your advice. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Can you say whether you have been 'researching…' or 'doing research on…' (whatever)?

Are you actually Asking whether you 'might/could/should do (whatever)' or did you really mean 'might could should…'?

@Alphabet That link didn't work for Chrome on my Mac…

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native English speaker, so maybe I made a mistake in the verbal usage.     I should have used 'research' as a transitive verb. As for your second question, I really mean the latter.